# assistance regarding android definitions and concepts

Tags: java, android, xml, view, android-studio

i'm a beginner in android development, so i'm finding it difficult to understand some of the technical terms used in android like xml files, .java files etc.

Is it possible to get the source code from the apk file obtained from the play store?

what is a "view", in e.g.

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v)
{
    Button button=(Button) v;
    ((Button) v).setText("clicked");

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try e.g. [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and don't wonder too much for now. a [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is an instance of a a class and if you don't understand that concept you might want to learn about the basics of Java first :)

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
 and http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html. Your main problem is, that you (apparently)  never programmed in Java before. So, instead of starting with Android development, start by learning the basics of Java.

Comment: @zapl _"a View is an instance of a a class"_ are you serious with that comment? You probably mean: "in your example `v` is an instance of the `View` class"

Comment: actually `v` is just a variable containing a reference to that instance

Comment: thnx for the assist guys, but what is View, why do I need to use the View, what is it refering to? I have programmed in C#, I have done completed a few Java tus, created a game...

Comment: @DonL. The wording was not the best but "a View" as in "a concrete View Object" is an instance of a class. @user2699451 Callbacks usually tell you which object is the source of the event. In your case a `Button`. `View` is the root of all ui elements e.g. `Button` is derived from `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll be able to understand the basics of android from the developer site itself

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

> Is it possible to get the source code from the apk file obtained from
>   the play store?

you wont be able to get the raw code, but you can get the resource files and some of the class files using the apktool.for thi syou've to get the apk file first..

http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/